# Problema con Array Associative

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código representativo:

```
$edadDeJuan = 30;

const EDADES = array(
    "Juan" => $edadDeJuan,
    "Raul" => 41,
    "Lucas" => 23
);
```

Resulta que **no puedo almacenar el valor de una variable dentro del objeto** EDADES (línea 4).
¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: EDADES no lo estas definiendo como un **objeto**, sino que al utilizar `const` lo estas definiendo como **constante**. A diferencia de las variables, una constante no puede cambiar su valor una vez establecida, y por ese mismo motivo no puede contener una variable entre sus valores aunque la definas como un array.

Comment: @masterguru Lo solucioné **declarando la constante con "define"**, quedó de la siguiente forma:
`$edadDeJuan = 30;  define("EDADES", array( "Juan" => $edadDeJuan, "Raul" => 41, "Lucas" => 23));`. Para acceder a algún valor:
`echo "Juan tiene " . EDADES["Juan"] . " años.";`